# Agregar en ArrayList en Java-NetBeans

Tags: java

Buenas soy nueva en esto de programación
Este programa se trata de una operadora, a en la cual se hacen registros de informacion del usuario y de su numero telefónico con su operadora, después de haber registrado esta información, existe otra opción en la cual debe permitir agregar mas teléfonos a un contacto ya existente pero,

No me muestra lo que agrego en la función  ***Agreg_Tel_Contacto***

Solo me muestra lo que ingreso en la función de registrar

//registrar

```
  public static void registrarContacto(ArrayList<Contacto> contactos){
    int res;
    ArrayList<Telefono>Telefonos =new ArrayList<Telefono>();
    String cedula, nombres, apellidos,numero,operadora;
    System.out.println("Ingrese la cedula");
    cedula=scan.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Ingrese el nombre");
    nombres=scan.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Ingrese los apellidos");
    apellidos=scan.nextLine();
    //registrar el telefono
    do{
    System.out.println("Ingrese el numero de telefono");
    numero= scan.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Ingrese el nombre de la operadora");
    operadora= scan.nextLine();
    
    Telefono objtelefono=new Telefono(numero,operadora);
    Telefonos.add(objtelefono);
    System.out.println("DESEA REGISTRAR OTRO TELEFONO 1)SI");
    res= scan.nextInt();
    scan.nextLine();
    }while(res==1);
    
    Contacto objContacto=new Contacto(cedula,nombres,apellidos,Telefonos);
    contactos.add(objContacto);//agregar al ArrayList        
}
```

//Listar

```
        public static void listarContactos(ArrayList<Contacto> contactos){
    for(int i=0; i<contactos.size();i++){
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("CEDULA"+contactos.get(i).getCedula());
        System.out.println("NOMBRES"+contactos.get(i).getNombres());
        System.out.println("APELLIDOS"+contactos.get(i).getApellidos());
        System.out.println("TELEFONOS");
        System.out.println();
    
    for(int j=0; j<contactos.get(i).getTelefonos().size();j++){
     contactos.get(i).getTelefonos().get(j).mostrarOperadora();

    }
}
}
```

//Agregar telefono a Contacto

```
  public static void Agreg_Tel_Contacto(ArrayList<Contacto> contactos){
  ArrayList<Telefono>Telefonos =new ArrayList<Telefono>();
  int res;
  
 String nombre_contacto,n_telef, n_oper,cedula = null, apellidos=null;
 System.out.println("Ingrese el nombre del contacto al que va a agregar un nuevo telefono");
 
 nombre_contacto=scan.nextLine();
 for(int i=0;i<contactos.size();i++){
     if(nombre_contacto==null ? contactos.get(i).getNombres()==null : nombre_contacto.equals(contactos.get(i).getNombres()) ){
         System.out.println("CEDULA"+contactos.get(i).getCedula());
        do{
    System.out.println("Ingrese el numero de telefono");
    n_telef= scan.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Ingrese el nombre de la operadora");
    n_oper= scan.nextLine();
    
    Telefono objtelefono=new Telefono(n_telef,n_oper);
    Telefonos.add(objtelefono);
    System.out.println("DESEA REGISTRAR OTRO TELEFONO 1)SI");
    res= scan.nextInt();
    scan.nextLine();
   
    }while(res==1);      
   }
   }   

       }
```

Estas son mis clases
****Telefono********

```
 package ejemploagendapoo;
 public class Telefono {

static void add(Telefono objtelefono) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}
private String numero;
private String nombreOperadora;

public Telefono(String numero, String nombreOperadora) {
    this.numero = numero;
    this.nombreOperadora = nombreOperadora;
}

public String getNumero() {
    return numero;
}

public void setNumero(String numero) {
    this.numero = numero;
}
   
       public void mostrarOperadora(){
    System.out.println("NUMERO"+numero);
    System.out.println("OPERADORA"+nombreOperadora);
}
}
```

************Contacto*************

```
  package ejemploagendapoo;
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 public class Contacto {
private String cedula;
private String nombres;
private String apellidos;
private ArrayList<Telefono>telefonos;

public Contacto() {
}

public Contacto(String cedula, String nombres, String apellidos, ArrayList<Telefono> telefonos) {
    this.cedula = cedula;
    this.nombres = nombres;
    this.apellidos = apellidos;
    this.telefonos = telefonos;
}

Contacto(ArrayList<Telefono> Telefonos) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}

public String getCedula() {
    return cedula;
}

public void setCedula(String cedula) {
    this.cedula = cedula;
}

public String getNombres() {
    return nombres;
}

public void setNombres(String nombres) {
    this.nombres = nombres;
}

public String getApellidos() {
    return apellidos;
}

public void setApellidos(String apellidos) {
    this.apellidos = apellidos;
}

public ArrayList<Telefono> getTelefonos() {
    return telefonos;
}

public void setTelefonos(ArrayList<Telefono> telefonos) {
    this.telefonos = telefonos;
} 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

En `Agreg_Tel_Contacto`, quiere agregar telefonos nuevos  a las contactes ya existentes, no?

Pero en su codigo, despues de `Telefonos.add(objtelefono)` dentro del *do while*, no guardas este Telefonos en ninguna contacto.

Puede hacer un poco de modificaion como aqui:

```java
public static void Agreg_Tel_Contacto(ArrayList<Contacto> contactos){
    
    ArrayList<Telefono>Telefonos =new ArrayList<Telefono>();
    
    int res;
    String nombre_contacto,n_telef, n_oper,cedula = null, apellidos=null;

    System.out.println("Ingrese el nombre del contacto al que va a agregar un nuevo telefono");
    nombre_contacto=scan.nextLine();

    for(int i=0;i<contactos.size();i++){
        if(nombre_contacto==null ? contactos.get(i).getNombres()==null : nombre_contacto.equals(contactos.get(i).getNombres()))
        {
            System.out.println("CEDULA"+contactos.get(i).getCedula());

            // declarar un nuevo ArrayList por cada contacto distinto
            Telefonos =new ArrayList<Telefono>();

            do{
                System.out.println("Ingrese el numero de telefono");
                n_telef= scan.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Ingrese el nombre de la operadora");
                n_oper= scan.nextLine();

                Telefono objtelefono=new Telefono(n_telef,n_oper);
                Telefonos.add(objtelefono);
                System.out.println("DESEA REGISTRAR OTRO TELEFONO 1)SI");
                res= scan.nextInt();
                scan.nextLine();

            }while(res==1); 

            // agrega los nuevos telefonos a los existentes en el contacto
            contactos.get(i).getTelefonos().addAll(Telefonos);
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias 
ya me funciona bien el código

Comment: @PaolaMateo si el código te ha funcionado y te ha servido, por favor, considera votar la respuesta como positiva y marcarla como aceptada.